# Netlogo - Creating a global mean for a value that is sometimes not existing

Tags: list, global, netlogo, mean, agent

I'm trying to measure the mean value of agents that are performing a certain acitivity. To calculate this value, I tried to use: `set mean-powerdemand mean [ powerdemand ] of agents with [ powerdemand > 0 ]`

To give some contexT: My model concerns charging electric cars. I want to measure the `powerdemand` of agents that are actually charging their car and thus have a `powerdemand > 0`. I want to exclude the non-charging agents for this mean calculation, as this would bring down the mean value. However, as there are moments in time (specifically at the start of the run) where no cars are charging, I am getting the error: `Can't find mean of a list with no numbers: []`

Does someone know a way to work around calculations with agent-own variables and/or lists that are sometimes empty?

I started of by calculating this value in a plot by using the same code. By doing so, it does not prohibit me from running the model, but since I want to use it as a reporter in the BehaviourSpace set-up, I want to make a global value of it.

Thanks.

Comment: Came up with a solution just now! Ran over it once more and came up with the following work-around by creating an if-statement beforehand: 

`if sum [ powerdemand ] of cars > 0 [ set mean-powerdemand mean [ powerdemand ] of agents with [ powerdemand > 0 ]`

Comment: If `[powerdemand] of cars` returned a list of all zeros, your check would result in your missing a valid mean.  This may never happen in your model, but it would be safer to use `if length [powerdemand] of cars > 0`.  That will insure that there is at least one item in the list.